# Pure CSS drop down menu issue in IE 6 and 7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a pure css menu with dropdowns, in IE8 and FF it works great, but compatibility mode for IE7 and IE6 it doesnt work.

The thing is, it does drop down - but then when the mouse goes over the main website banner below, which has a massive image in it, the drop menu disappears...

I do not want to drop links here, so, you can probably find the site from my profile.

But here is some code. Menu first up.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="***.php" title="Unihost Web Hosting Home Page">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Company</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="***.php" title="About Unihost">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="***.php" title="We're going green, are you?">Going Green</a></li>
<li><a href="***.php" title="Unihost Privacy Policy">Privacy policy</a></li>

<li><a href="***.php" title="Unihost Terms and Conditions">Terms and conditions</a></li>    
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Products</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="***.php" title="Register a domain with us" target="_blank">Domain Registrations</a></li>    
<li><a href="***.php" title="PHP Web hosting packages">PHP Web Hosting Packages</a></li>
<li><a href="***.php" title="Our E-mail hosting packages">Email Hosting Packages</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Contact us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="***.php" title="Contact support" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="***.php" title="Pre-sales Questions" target="_blank">Pre-sales Questions</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="">Client Area</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="***.php" target="_blank">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="***.php " target="_blank">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="***" target="_blank">Client Area</a></li>
<li><a href="***" target="_blank">Knowledgebase</a></li>

<li><a href="***" target="_blank">Help Ticket System</a></li>
</ul>
</li>  
</ul>
```

Css Second up

```
ul {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:700;
list-style:none;
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul li {
display:block;
position:relative;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}

li ul {
display:none;
}

ul li a {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#c00;
border-top:1px solid #ededed;
background:#ededed;
margin-left:1px;
white-space:nowrap;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:8px 15px;
}

ul li a:hover {
background:#c00;
color:#fff;
}

li:hover ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
border-right:0;
}

li:hover li {
float:none;
font-size:11px;
border-right:0;
}

li:hover a {
background:#444;
color:#fff;
border-top:1px solid #555;
border-right:0;
text-align:left;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
background:#dedede;
color:#c00;
border-right:0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest completely redo your html, this time using tables only for tabular data...

Comment: I see, so - going div and css is they way forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure CSS menus have a number of problems, not least the [diagonal problem](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/343/common-web-app-usability-gotchas/415#415). I'd suggest switching to Javascript - this should solve the browser compatibility problem and make the menu more usable.

If you are using jQuery I recommend [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).

Comment: Thanks - seems like Ill have to go for Java then

Comment: As a big plus, Superfish is keyboard accessible

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you will have to resort to javascript for your menu to work in IE6. I had written an article on instantshift you might want to have a look at:

- [Create Simple Dropdown Menu Using jQuery](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/07/16/create-simple-dropdown-menu-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options for getting the menu to work in IE6. It sounds like you're using compatibility mode in IE8 to test - this is definitely not analogous to actually using IE6 to look at the site.

As far as getting a pure CSS dropdown to work in IE6 goes, the simple answer is: you can't, because IE6 doesn't recognise the `:hover` pseudo-class on anything other than an `<a>`.

[IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) is a fantastic JS library that corrects CSS bugs and adds unsupported features to older versions of IE, it's well worth a look.

You could also do your bit for encouraging your users to upgrade by implementing Pushup, which you can find at pushuptheweb.com (sorry, can only post 1 link).

To be honest, you really should do as the other poster suggested and strip the tables out of your markup. That's a very outdated layout technique which could be replaced with a very small amount of semantic HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for this - I only saw his comment now

Answer (score 0):

First thing, IE6 is dead, [IE6 Funeral](http://ie6funeral.com/)

Second, for IE7 you may have to put z-index in you `ul` and wrap your image with `div` and put z-index on it. The z-index of `ul` should be higher than the z-index of the `div` that you wrap with your image.

Comment: I get this and will try it out thanks, but, looking at my analytics, IE6 is not long dead in our Country. So, I'm going to have to cater for them as well. That said, Im really trying to stay away from Java ;-) For the menu at least.

Comment: If I hold a funeral for rob waminal does that mean he is dead? :p

Comment: indeed. ie6 like anything else that is microsuck product.